# The same Cypher query yields inconsistent results between the SDK and the browser, with several Relationships missing

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I suspect that I have encountered a bug. When querying with the Go SDK, the data results obtained are inconsistent with those in the Neo4j browser, with several Relationships missing.

Neo4j Version: Neo4j Kernel 5.12.0 community

Neo4j Mode: Single instance

Driver version: Go driver v5.12.0

Operating System: centos

My Cypher is

```
MATCH (n1:AAA_IngressOfSecurityGroup {AssetsAccountId:"aaaa"})-[:IngressOfSecurityGroup]->(n2:AAA_SecurityGroup {AssetsAccountId:"aaaa"})-[:SecurityGroupOfNetworkInterface]->(n3:AAA_NetworkInterface {AssetsAccountId:"aaaa"})-[:NetworkInterfaceOfCvm]->(n4:AAA_CvmInstance {AssetsAccountId:"aaaa",AssetUniqueId:"aaaa-165d2740e7fa",AssetsVersion:"1702108924"}) WHERE n4.InstanceState = 'RUNNING' AND n4.RestrictState = 'NORMAL' AND n1.Action = 'ACCEPT' AND (n1.Ipv6CidrBlock = "::/0" OR n1.CidrBlock = "0.0.0.0/0") AND toLower(n1.Port) = 'all' AND (toLower(n1.Protocol) = 'tcp' or toLower(n1.Protocol) = 'udp' or toLower(n1.Protocol)= 'all' )   WITH n1, n2, n3, n4 WHERE ALL (groupId IN n3.GroupSet WHERE   NOT EXISTS {     MATCH (n2_other:AAA_SecurityGroup {AssetsAccountId:"aaaa", SecurityGroupId: groupId})-[:IngressOfSecurityGroup]->(n1_other:AAA_IngressOfSecurityGroup)     WHERE n1_other.Action = 'DROP' AND ((n1_other.CidrBlock = "0.0.0.0/0" OR n1_other.Ipv6CidrBlock = "::/0") AND toLower(n1_other.Port) = 'all') AND NOT EXISTS {       MATCH (n1_smaller:AAA_IngressOfSecurityGroup)-[:IngressOfSecurityGroup]->(n2_other)       WHERE toInteger(n1_smaller.PolicyIndex) < toInteger(n1_other.PolicyIndex)     }   } )  OPTIONAL MATCH p2 = (n7:AAA_PublicIp {AssetsAccountId:"aaaa"})-[:PublicIpToVpc]->(n6:AAA_Vpc {AssetsAccountId:"aaaa"})-[:SubnetsInVPC]->(n5:AAA_Subnet {AssetsAccountId:"aaaa"})-[:NetworkInterfaceInSubnet]->(n3) WHERE p2 IS NOT NULL  OPTIONAL MATCH p3 = (n8:AAA_Eip {AssetsAccountId:"aaaa"})-[:EipOToVpc]->(n6)-[:SubnetsInVPC]->(n5)-[:NetworkInterfaceInSubnet]->(n3) WHERE p3 IS NOT NULL      WITH DISTINCT n4, n1, n2, n3, n6, n7, p2, p3  RETURN n1, n2, n3,n4, n6, n7, p2, p3
```

The code I use to process the data returned from Neo4j is as follows.

```
result, session, err := global.Neo4j.RunCypherQuery(body.Cypher, nil)
    if err != nil {
        logger.Log.Error("RunCypherQuery error: " + err.Error())
        response := responses.NewErrorResponse(responses.StatusCodeUnknownErr, err.Error())
        c.JSON(http.StatusOK, response)
        return
    }

    var nodes []neo4j.Node
    var relationships []neo4j.Relationship

    seenNodes := make(map[int64]bool)
    seenRelationships := make(map[int64]bool)
    for result.Next() {
        record := result.Record()
        for _, value := range record.Values {
            if value == nil {
                continue
            }
            switch v := value.(type) {
            case neo4j.Node:
                if _, found := seenNodes[v.Id]; !found {
                    seenNodes[v.GetId()] = true
                    nodes = append(nodes, v)
                }
            case neo4j.Relationship:
                if _, found := seenRelationships[v.Id]; !found {
                    seenRelationships[v.GetId()] = true
                    relationships = append(relationships, v)
                }
            case neo4j.Path:
                for _, node := range v.Nodes {
                    if _, found := seenNodes[node.Id]; !found {
                        seenNodes[node.GetId()] = true
                        nodes = append(nodes, node)
                    }
                }
                for _, rel := range v.Relationships {
                    if _, found := seenRelationships[rel.Id]; !found {
                        seenRelationships[rel.GetId()] = true
                        relationships = append(relationships, rel)
                    }
                }
            case []interface{}:
                for _, item := range v {
                    switch elem := item.(type) {
                    case neo4j.Node:
                        if _, found := seenNodes[elem.GetId()]; !found {
                            seenNodes[elem.GetId()] = true
                            nodes = append(nodes, elem)
                        }
                    case neo4j.Relationship:
                        if _, found := seenRelationships[elem.GetId()]; !found {
                            seenRelationships[elem.GetId()] = true
                            relationships = append(relationships, elem)
                        }
                    default:
                        logger.Log.Error("Unexpected type in []interface{}: %T", item)
                        response := responses.NewErrorResponse(responses.StatusCodeUnknownErr, errors.New(fmt.Sprintf("Unexpected type in []interface{}: %T", item)).Error())
                        c.JSON(http.StatusOK, response)
                        return
                    }
                }
            default:
                logger.Log.Error("Unexpected type: %T", v)
                response := responses.NewErrorResponse(responses.StatusCodeUnknownErr, errors.New(fmt.Sprintf("Unexpected type: %T", v)).Error())
                c.JSON(http.StatusOK, response)
                return
            }
        }
    }
```

```
func (c *Client) RunCypherQuery(query string, params map[string]interface{}) (neo4j.Result, neo4j.Session, error) {
    session := c.driver.NewSession(neo4j.SessionConfig{})
    fmt.Println(query)
    result, err := session.Run(query, params)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, session, err
    }
    return result, session, nil
}
```

in neo4j desktop search result is

[image]

in my code search result is

[image]

The position marked with a red "X" indicates that no results were found.

In the RunCypherQuery method, the data for these three Relationships were not found in the returned result.

Answer (score 0):

In the topmost MATCH statement, I didn't define a name for the Relationships, such as r1, so the returned data did not include these relationships. Oddly enough, the browser managed to return data using the unnamed Cypher, which might involve some behind-the-scenes processing. By modifying the Cypher query, I have resolved this issue.

Comment: In neo4j browser, there is an option in the settings: "Connect result nodes". When this option is enabled the browser will issue additional queries to retrieve the relationships between the nodes displayed on screen.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is the correct explanation.